# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/test/TestUtils

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I am trying to write test cases for `Kafka producers` and `Consumers`, here it is the sample program

```
package com.nuovo.streamseer.sentinel.tocassandra;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.junit.Test;
import kafka.admin.AdminUtils;
import kafka.admin.RackAwareMode;
import kafka.server.KafkaConfig;
import kafka.server.KafkaServer;
import kafka.utils.MockTime;
import kafka.utils.TestUtils;
import kafka.utils.Time;
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$;
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils;
import kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


public class KafkaProducerIT {

private static final String ZKHOST = "127.0.0.1";
private static final String BROKERHOST = "127.0.0.1";
private static final String BROKERPORT = "9092";
private static final String TOPIC = "test";

@Test
public void producerTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    // setup Zookeeper
    EmbeddedZookeeper zkServer = new EmbeddedZookeeper();
    String zkConnect = ZKHOST + ":" + zkServer.port();
    ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(zkConnect, 30000, 30000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
    ZkUtils zkUtils = ZkUtils.apply(zkClient, false);

    // setup Broker
    Properties brokerProps = new Properties();
    brokerProps.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", zkConnect);
    brokerProps.setProperty("broker.id", "0");
    brokerProps.setProperty("log.dirs", Files.createTempDirectory("kafka-").toAbsolutePath().toString());
    brokerProps.setProperty("listeners", "PLAINTEXT://" + BROKERHOST +":" + BROKERPORT);
    brokerProps.setProperty("offsets.topic.replication.factor" , "1");
    KafkaConfig config = new KafkaConfig(brokerProps);
    Time mock = new MockTime();
    KafkaServer kafkaServer = TestUtils.createServer(config, mock);

    // create topic
    AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, TOPIC, 1, 1, new Properties(), RackAwareMode.Disabled$.MODULE$);

    // setup producer
    Properties producerProps = new Properties();
    producerProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", BROKERHOST + ":" + BROKERPORT);
    producerProps.setProperty("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
    producerProps.setProperty("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    KafkaProducer<Integer, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<Integer, byte[]>(producerProps);

    // setup consumer
    Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
    consumerProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", BROKERHOST + ":" + BROKERPORT);
    consumerProps.setProperty("group.id", "group0");
    consumerProps.setProperty("client.id", "consumer0");
    consumerProps.setProperty("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
    consumerProps.setProperty("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    consumerProps.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");  // to make sure the consumer starts from the beginning of the topic
    KafkaConsumer<Integer, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(TOPIC));

    // send message
    ProducerRecord<Integer, byte[]> data = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, 42, "test-message".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    producer.send(data);
    producer.close();

    // starting consumer
    ConsumerRecords<Integer, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(5000);
    assertEquals(1, records.count());
    Iterator<ConsumerRecord<Integer, byte[]>> recordIterator = records.iterator();
    ConsumerRecord<Integer, byte[]> record = recordIterator.next();
    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
    assertEquals(42, (int) record.key());
    assertEquals("test-message", new String(record.value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    kafkaServer.shutdown();
    zkClient.close();
    zkServer.shutdown();
}
}
```

`pom` dependencies are

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>0.10.1.0</version>
<classifier>test</classifier>
```

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Getting the following errors

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/test/TestUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.<init>(TestUtils.scala:61)
at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.<clinit>(TestUtils.scala)
at kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedZookeeper.scala:29)
at com.nuovo.streamseer.sentinel.tocassandra.KafkaProducerIT.producerTest(KafkaProducerIT.java:52)
```

why it is getting.. I tried by changing the version numbers but those didn't work, actually I got this code from online sites, there they suggested some dependencies, when I use those dependencies I got compilation errors, after doing some research I and changing version numbers then all compilation errors are gone, now I am getting this error(above mentioned error).

Comment: You have different versions of both dependencies. I'd make them both either 0.11.0.0 or 0.10.1.0.

Comment: If I use any one version for both  `0.11.0.0` or `0.10.1.0`, I am getting compilation errors like `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.MockTime not found`

Comment: `org.apache.kafka.kafka_2.11` will contain `kafka-clients`, so just remove the `test` classifier and only use that one dependency. Should help...

Comment: used only `kafka_211`, removed `test` classifier and `clients` but still getting compilation errors at `MockTime` and `TestUtils`, used latest `kafka_211` version `1.0.0` still same problem